# Extracting filenames without the extension inside a list with a Shell Script

Tags: python

Provided I have a string with multiple path files that look something like this:

"mydrive/mypath/myapp/first_app.java, mydrive/mypath/myapp/second_app.java, mydrive/mypath/myapp/third_app.java". 
From this string I'd like to extract only the file names without the file extension and build a new list of strings that will look like this:

"first_app, second_app, third_app" etc..

My current implementation is in Python and it looks like this:

```
from sys import argv

incoming_strings = argv
clean_strings_list = []
if isinstance(incoming_strings, list):
    for string_to_cut in incoming_strings:
        if "app" in string_to_cut:
            string_to_cut_ = string_to_cut.split('/')
            string_to_cut__ = string_to_cut_[len(string_to_cut_) - 1]
            string_to_cut = string_to_cut__.split('.')[0]
            clean_strings_list.append(string_to_cut)
    print(clean_strings_list)
else:
    string_to_cut_ = incoming_strings.split('/')
    string_to_cut__ = string_to_cut_[len(string_to_cut_)-1]
    string_to_cut = string_to_cut__.split('.')[0]
    print(string_to_cut)
```

I am required to implement the following code with a Bash script. What would be the proper way to do that?
Thanks!

Comment: To split the string into pieces, you can use `echo $yourstring | tr , "\n"` . For removing the directory part and the _.java_ extension, the easiest approach (from the viewpoint of programming effort) is to use the `basename` command, though other possibilities exist too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has quite many solutions for your issue, one suggestion here:

**Python**

```py
>>>st = 'mydrive/mypath/myapp/first_app.java, mydrive/mypath/myapp/second_app.java, mydrive/mypath/myapp/third_app.java'
>>>import os
>>>for s in st.strip().split(","):
...    fname = os.path.basename(s).split(".")[0]
...    print(fname)

first_app
second_app
third_app
```

**Bash**

```sh
st='mydrive/mypath/myapp/first_app.java, mydrive/mypath/myapp/second_app.java, mydrive/mypath/myapp/third_app.java'
OLDIFS=$IFS   // get default IFS
IFS=","  // set comma as a delimiter
read -ra ADDR <<< "$st"     // split st into array
for i in "${ADDR[@]}"; do 
    filename=$(basename -- "$i")    // get filename from filepath
    echo "${filename%.*}"   // get filename only - without extension
done
IFS=$OLDIFS  // reset to default value
```

**Output**:

```sh
first_app
second_app
third_app
```

[Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash)

Comment: Your suggestion uses _Python_. The OP was looking for a _bash_ program.

Comment: @user1934428, thanks for reminding, I just focus on his tag. Updated answer with bash script already.

Comment: Since you solved this by fiddeling with IFS, it might be better to save the original IFS into a variable and restore it later from there. We don't know in which context your code snippet will be used, and maybe the IFS has been modified already. This is one reason why I don't like so much changing IFS in the middle of a script, although I'm well aware that this is considered common and good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Using bash, you could split the path on ',' using `IFS` like,

```
$ path="mydrive/mypath/myapp/first_app.java, mydrive/mypath/myapp/second_app.java, mydrive/mypath/myapp/third_app.java"
$ IFS=, read -ra paths <<<"$path" # read into an array, by splitting the path on `,`
$ for path in "${paths[@]}"
> do
>   filename="${path##*/}" # strip whatever is before final /
>   filename="${filename%.*}" # strip the extension
>   echo "$filename"
> done
first_app
second_app
third_app
```

You could just use `os.path` or `pathlib`(i recommend, if you are on python3),

```
>>> path = "mydrive/mypath/myapp/first_app.java, mydrive/mypath/myapp/second_app.java, mydrive/mypath/myapp/third_app.java"
>>> import os
>>> [os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(p)) for p in path.split(',')]
[('first_app', '.java'), ('second_app', '.java'), ('third_app', '.java')]
>>> import pathlib
>>> details = [(pathlib.Path(p).stem, pathlib.Path(p).suffix) for p in path.split(',')]
[('first_app', '.java'), ('second_app', '.java'), ('third_app', '.java')]
```

And if you just want names,

```
>>> names_without_exts, _ = zip(*details)
>>> names_without_exts
('first_app', 'second_app', 'third_app')
```

or directly use,

```
>>> [os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(p))[0] for p in path.split(',')]
['first_app', 'second_app', 'third_app']
>>> [pathlib.Path(p).stem for p in path.split(',')]
['first_app', 'second_app', 'third_app']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to extract only the part you need by using `re.search`.

```py
import re
strings=["mydrive/mypath/myapp/first_app.java", "mydrive/mypath/myapp/second_app.java", "mydrive/mypath/myapp/third_app.java"]
for string in strings:
    a = re.search("\/([^\/]*)\.[^\.\/]*$", string)
    a.group(1)
```

This will produce:

```
'first_app'
'second_app'
'third_app'
```

You can test this on [regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/gKMxzG/3).