# Script to extract only the MaxMind GeoLite2 Country database from gzip containing multiple files

Tags: linux, bash, maxmind, gunzip

Recently MaxMind changed their download policy, and the old simple format is no longer available. The new file format looks like this: `GeoLite2-Country_20191231.tar.gz`, and inside we have a folder with the same name containing two additional files.

Although there is an option to delete the `date` parameter from the link, it seems that the downloaded file will still contain the date.

Now, the problem is to extract that `GeoLite2-Country.mmdb` from the gzip file having that variable name programmatically.

The unzip part existing in my old script was this:

```
gunzip -c "$1"GeoLite2-Country.mmdb.gz > "$1"GeoLite2-Country.mmdb
```

The question is how to modify the above part for the new situation. Or, maybe someone knows another way to solve the same problem. Thanks in advance.

The folder structure:

```
-+ Geolite2-Country_YYYYMMDD.tar.gz:
 |-+ Geolite2-Country_YYYYMMDD
   |- licence.txt
   |- copyright.txt
   |- Geolite2-Country.mmdb
```

What I need is `Geolite2-Country.mmdb` in the current folder of gzip file.

Comment: Quick and dirty? `GeoLite2-Country_*.mmdb.gz` would work if you only have one of those files in the directory.

Comment: @kaylum I said that there are multiple files now, not just one, and the database name doesn't match the folder name.

Comment: Then write a shell script with a `for` loop. The `for` loop would iterate over `GeoLite2-Country*.mmdb.gz`. Then [extract the filename without extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash) for the `mmdb` file name.

Comment: @kaylum Thanks for the idea, but I'm not so familiar with loops. I updated the question with the folder structure, can you try to write the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tar -tf /GeoLite2-City.tar.gz | grep mmdb | xargs tar -xf  /GeoLite2-City.tar.gz --strip-components 1 -C /
```

Just fix source and destination paths