# Split a string by awk and print everything but the last two splits

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a string `/home/lamma/local-blast/termitomycesBGI/short_reads/F19FTSEUHT1394.IC0035-2A_1.fq.gz`
and I am using awk to split the string:

```
echo  /home/lamma/local-blast/termitomycesBGI/short_reads/F19FTSEUHT1394.IC0035-2A.fasta.gz | awk -F'.[^.]*$' '{ print $1 }'
```

Which returns:

```
/home/lamma/local-blast/termitomycesBGI/short_reads/F19FTSEUHT1394.IC0035-2A.fasta
```

But  want it to return:

```
/home/lamma/local-blast/termitomycesBGI/short_reads/F19FTSEUHT1394.IC0035-2A
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Just use .fasta as the delimiter : `awk -F ".fasta" '{ print $1}'`

Comment: This would work but the file extension might not always be the same for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract filename and extension in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash)

Comment: What's the rule then to remove some parts of the string?

Comment: @CorentinLimier This seems like it would work aslong as you didn't have "." in the filename at points other than for the file extension, which unfortunatly I somttimes do :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Split a string by awk and print everything but the last two splits

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} {$NF=$(NF-1)=""; NF-=2} 1' <<< '/home/lamma/local-blast/termitomycesBGI/short_reads/F19FTSEUHT1394.IC0035-2A.fasta.gz'
```

```
/home/lamma/local-blast/termitomycesBGI/short_reads/F19FTSEUHT1394.IC0035-2A
```

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following. You could use Parameter expansion of bash.

```
val="/home/lamma/local-blast/termitomycesBGI/short_reads/F19FTSEUHT1394.IC0035-2A.fq.gz"
echo "${val%_*}"
```

Output will be as follows.

```
/home/lamma/local-blast/termitomycesBGI/short_reads/F19FTSEUHT1394.IC0035-2A
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** As per anubhava sir's comments, in case variable has `.` itself then try following using `rev` + `awk` solution.

```
echo "$val" | rev | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} {$1=$2="";sub(/^\.+/,"");print $0}' | rev
```

---

---

***EDIT2:*** Adding a `sed` + `rev` solution.

```
echo "$val" | rev | sed 's/[^.]*.[^.]*.\(.*\)/\1/' | rev
```

Comment: This indeed works, is this just a better method than awk or?

Comment: @Lamma, In this condition IMHO yes it is better command for shown sample.

Comment: What are the limitations of this method and what would I google to find out more?

Comment: Hi @RavinderSingh13: If input is `val='/home/lamma/local-blast/termitomycesBGI/short_reads/F19FTSEUHT1394.IC0035-2A.fasta.gz'` then this will give `/home/lamma/local-blast/termitomycesBGI/short` which may not be what OP wants.

Comment: @anubhava, Thanks sir, I added EDIT solution now sir, please do lemme know if EDIT solution looks Good now sir.

Comment: @Lamma, it is called Parameter expansion of bash, see this link https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html  it has great information in it, I also added awk solution here, lemme know in case of any more queries.