# How to remove all parts of a filename after the first dot on mac

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, rename, filenames

I'm trying to do this on the mac terminal

I want to strip all the fields after the first dot on a filename but keep the extension at the end, and there can be an arbitrary length of dots.

Input:

```
file1.some.stuff.mp3 file2.other.stuff.stuff.mp3 file3.some.thing.mp3 file4.one.two.three.four.mp3
```

Expected output:

```
file1.mp3 file2.mp3 file3.mp3 file4.mp3
```

I have all the files on the same folder.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what did it emit? Edit your post to include this information.

Comment: Say that `f` is a variable with `file1.some.stuff.mp3` as value, `${f/.*/}` will result in `file1`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a string by awk and print everything but the last two splits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59773339/split-a-string-by-awk-and-print-everything-but-the-last-two-splits)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the filenames are guaranteed to have at least one `.` with non-empty strings preceding and following a `.`, this is a matter of simple parameter expansions.

```
for f in file1.some.stuff.mp3 file2.other.stuff.stuff.mp3 file3.some.thing.mp3 file4.one.two.three.four.mp3; do
    echo "${f%%.*}.${f##*.}"
done
```

produces

```
file1.mp3
file2.mp3
file3.mp3
file4.mp3
```

In the directory where the files exit, use something like

```
for f in *.mp3; do
```

to iterate over all MP3 files.

Comment: Yes! this prints in console what i need but with the echo it only prints it in console it doesnt change the actual file names, which command could i use to do that action?

Comment: `mv -- "$f" "${f%%.*}.${f##*.}"`, but I would recommend making sure that this doesn't result in two or more original files being renamed the same before actually executing the `mv` command.

Comment: Yep thanks i actually almost butchered a lot of files there that worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Using bash variable substitution you may achieve the following:

```sh
for i in file1.some.stuff.mp3 file2.other.stuff.stuff.mp3 file3.some.thing.mp3
do
  echo "${i/.*./.}"
done
```

`${i/.*./.}` means to replace `.*.` by `.`. That is, it will match `.some.stuff.` in `file1.some.stuff.mp3` and `.b.c.d.` in `a.b.c.d.e`.

In the **parameter expansion** section of `man bash`:

> ${parameter/pattern/string}
>                 Pattern substitution.  The pattern is expanded to produce a pattern just as in  pathname  expansion.   Parameter  is
>                 expanded  and the longest match of pattern against its value is replaced with string.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in `ls *.mp3`; do NAMES=`echo $i|cut -d. -f1`; mv "$i" "$NAMES.mp3"; done
```