# Find/list only file types recursive in a directory

Tags: linux, bash, list, find, file-type

how can i search for files and give only a list of mimes or types out.

example:

```
dir
-file1.pdf
-file2.pdf
-dir2
--file3.png
--file4.pdf
```

wished output:

```
pdf
png
```

**Edit**

Found also a solution, but does not make a difference between upper and lowercase and also not .peng and .png

```
find . -type f -printf '%f\n' | sed 's/^.*\.//' | sort -u
```

Comment: `find dir -type f | grep -o '...$' | sort -u`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find`'s `-exec` option together with [any solution that extracts the extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/965053/6770384). Then pipe through `sort -u` to remove duplicates.

```
find dir -type f -exec bash -c 'printf %s\\n "${@##*.}"' x {} + | sort -u
```

Files without extensions will be listed too. To filter them out add the option `-name '*\.*'` before `-exec`.

Comment: this gave me a error:  find: missing argument to `-exec'

Comment: @Vergil My bad. I forgot the `{}`, see the edited answer. Thank you for the feedback.