# Cannot use a variable to assign another variable in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have tried assigning my bash variable and it works fine when i echo it. But as soon as i use the variable to assign another variable, it gives an error, that the command not exists.

```
dbFileName=hello123.mv.*
dbFile=$($dbFileName | sed -e 's|'.mv.*'|''|')
echo "$dbFile"
```

I want to alter the string stored in one variable and remove mv.* from the end.

This gives out the error that "hello123.mv.* : Command not found"

Comment: also; echo $dbFileName | sed -e 's|'.mv.*'|''|' gives proper result

Comment: $dbFileName contains the value "hello123.mv.something" 

You cannot just pass a string through a pipe, you'll have to use echo $dbFileName

Comment: This is an easier way to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash

Comment: @V.Bhanderi : You are running the content of `dbFileName` as a program. Since no filename in the working directory seems to match the pattern `hello123.mv.*`, this string is taken as the name of the program to be executed. Since you also don't have a program namedn `hello123.mv.*` in your PATH, you end up with this error message.

Comment: @V.Bhanderi please take a look at  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use parameter expansion with `%` which will remove characters from the end of the string or `#` which will remove characters from the beginning of the string. If you use a single one of those characters, the smallest matching string will be removed. If you double the character, the longest will be removed.

```
dbFileName="hello123.mv.whateverhere"
echo ${dbFileName%.mv*} # hello123
dbFile=${dbFileName%.mv*}
echo ${dbFile} # hello123
```