# How to remove all characters from after ".xml"

Tags: bash, unix

In a Bash script, I would like to remove everything after".xml" of all the file in the directory
for e.g.

i have two files for now but can be more:

```
- EXP_GP_00001586_48729648.xml_81234551334_48821189
- EXP_GP_00001454_170375138.xml_48821189
```

could appreciate some quick help

Comment: could you clarify the context in which you want to do so (for example bash script, python, C++...) ? because I doubt you're expecting an answer like "rename them manually" :-).

Comment: it is bash script , actually the whole issue is i am running a loop which check for some conditions and if it is true then it should move the  file to a particular directory with the name of above file example EXP_GP_00001454_170375138.xml and so on till xml only.

Comment: i tried some commands but does not seems to be working like f1=`basename $file | cut -f1 -c"xml"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a bash script, your problem looks like removing the extension of a file.
And that case have been treated here : [Extract filename and extension in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash)

You can easily adapt it to your problem :

```
FILE=EXP_GP_00001586_48729648.xml_81234551334_48821189
mv $FILE ${FILE%.xml*}.xml
```

Comment: for file in /home/insahr27/*EXP_GP*
do
if [ `stat --format=%Y $file` -le $(( `date +%s` - 1800 )) ] && [ -f "$file" ]; then

   mv $file /home/outbound/
   mv $file ${file%.xml*}.xml

else
    echo "no files to collect"
fi
done                                                                                                                                          i tried this but it say no such file in directory  mv: cannot stat '/home/outbound/EXP_GP_00001454_170375138.xml_48821189': No such file or directory

Comment: above is the loop i have used and checked for files modification time and then trying to move the file with new name as you showed but it seems some error

Comment: you've got an error because you are trying to move the file twice in `mv $file /home/outbound/ && mv $file ${file%.xml*}.xml`, the first `mv` really move the file, and the second one is failing because the file doesn't exist anymore (because you moved it). You can do both in one call : `mv $file /home/outbound/${file%.xml*}.xml`

Comment: Thanks it worked, sorry i am new but when running in a loop first run does it all properly when in continuation it run second time it shows the message

Comment: stderr=mv: '/home/outbound/EXP_GP_00001600_49334826.xml_820541123234' 
and '/home/outbound/ftp/EXP_GP_00001600_49334826.xml' are the same file

Comment: could you please help to know how to avoid this message

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't help you more without more information, could you post a code snippet ? because the 2 files you mention are obviously not the same (they are not in the same folder)

Comment: or maybe `/home/outbound/ftp`is a symlink to `/home/outbound`

Comment: #!/bin/bash

#$1 - Order number

cd /home/outbound

rm *$1*

#for the remaining files check and process further:

for file in /home/outbound/*EXP_GP*
do
   f1=`basename $file`
   if [ -f "$file" ];then

     if  [ `stat --format=%Y $file` -le $(( `date +%s` - 1800 )) ]; then

        mv $file /home/outbound/ftp/${f1%.xml*}.xml

     else
        echo "no files to collect"
     fi
   else
        echo "no files to collect"

   fi
done

Comment: how do we compare file under a bunch of files present in a directory and if match found rename the file found for e.g if file name of the match file is abc.xml-1 then it should rename it to abc.xml-2 and again if same same file found for second iteration it should rename it to abc.xml-3

Comment: if you have another question, please post a new one. and don't forget to mark this one as "resolved" by accepting one of the answers, if you think your question has been answered.

Comment: if this answer helped you, don't forget to vote up or even accept it if you think it is answering your question