# Pipe the output of basename to string substitution

Tags: bash, pipe, file-extension, string-substitution, basename

I need the basename of a file that is given as an argument to a bash script. The basename should be stripped of its file extension.
Let's assume `$1 = "/somefolder/andanotherfolder/myfile.txt"`, the desired output would be `"myfile"`.

The current attempt creates an intermediate variable that I would like to avoid:

```
BASE=$(basename "$1")
NOEXT="${BASE%.*}"
```

My attempt to make this a one-liner would be piping the output of basename. However, I do not know how to pipe stdout to a string substitution.

EDIT: this needs to work for multiple file extensions with possibly differing lengths, hence the string substitution attempt as given above.

Comment: Put a semicolon between them and it becomes a one-liner.

Comment: `noext=$(basename "$1" .txt)`

Comment: Please look at `man basename`.

Comment: Thanks.
For the first answer by @oguzismail: How do I replace the variable name "BASE" once it is a one liner?

Comment: @KamilCuk That only works for one specific file ending (txt in this case).

Comment: @Cyrus I did. Unless I'm missing something this is not possible with basename alone.

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/965072/11934850 of Petesh to a similar question.

Comment: @KamilCuk : This suggestion implies that we already know that the extension is `.txt`. From the code the OP provided, in particular the calculation of `NOEXT`, I would assume that the extension can be anything.

Comment: @SaschaDoerdelmann The answer you mention explains how to do it in two steps, which is the current approach that I have described in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not Zoidberg ?
Ehhmm.. I meant why not remove the ext before going for basename ?

```
basename "${1%.*}"
```

Unless of course you have directory paths with dots, then you'll have to use basename before and remove the extension later:

```
echo $(basename "$1") | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "." }; { print $1 }'
```

The awk solution will remove **anything** after the first dot from the filename.

There's a regular expression based solution which uses sed to remove only the extension after last dot if it exists:

```
echo $(basename "$1") | sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/'
```

This could even be improved if you're sure that you've got alphanumeric extensions of 3-4 characters (eg: mp3, mpeg, jpg, txt, json...)

```
echo $(basename "$1") | sed 's/\(.*\)\.[[:alnum:]]\{3\}$/\1/'
```

Comment: I really like the first option for the sake of simplicity and readability. 
Paths including dots could be an issue though.

Comment: Actually, I just tried this with a path containing foldernames using dots and it worked out.

Comment: Indeed it will work even with paths that contains dots, but only if your filename has contains a dot too. if $1= '/some.dir/myfile' it would cut at the first trailing dot it finds. The second version is just more safe to use, even if it's uglier ;) But bash isn't the most beautiful script lang anyway IMO ;)

Comment: You're right. 
On the flipside of the coin: The awk solution does not work properly if the filename itself contains a dot before the file ending.

Comment: So after some more thought it seems like the cleanest, yet ugly solution may be this:
`echo $(basename "$1") | rev | cut -d"." -f 2- | rev`
It will get the basename and remove everything after the last `.` of the basename.

Comment: That's a lot of uglyness indeed. I added a sed based solution which uses regular expressions to restrict to file extensions.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```sh
NEXT="$(basename -- "${1%.*}")"
```

Testing:

```sh
set -- '/somefolder/andanotherfolder/myfile.txt'
NEXT="$(basename -- "${1%.*}")"
echo "$NEXT"
```

> `myfile`

Alternatively:

```sh
set -- "${1%.*}"; NEXT="${1##*/}"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NOEXT="${1##*/}"; NOEXT="${NOEXT%.*}"
```

Comment: avoid intermediate variable ;)

Comment: Ha! sneaky one ;p

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$ [[ $var =~ [^/]*$ ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH%.*}
myfile
```