# How to crop file names though pipe on bash

Tags: bash

New to linux and bash,
with ls command I can list file names in a directory. My directory contains text files. I want to pipe the listed file names to some other command that would remove the file extensions, How can I achieve that

```
ls
filename1.txt
filename2.txt
```

to

```
ls | somecommand
filename1
filename2
```

any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/965053/1707353)?

Comment: Using `ls` like this is not a best practice to begin with, see [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 0):

Typically edit streams with *Stream EDitor* (sed). You could just remove everything from a comma till the end. With zero terminated strings, one could use `-print0` and GNU `sed` version with `-z`.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%f\n" | sed 's/\..*//'
```

If all files are `*.txt` you could use `basename`, which allows to work with zero terminated strings with `-print0` and `xargs -0`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' | xargs -I{} basename {} .txt
```

[Do not use `ls` in scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead).