# Remove prefix from auto string bash script

Tags: linux, bash

**Solved**

Used `cut -c 4-` in code and added new variable CURFILE1 which is used to print file `"$CURFILE1" {`

```
CURFILE="$(basename "$file")"
CURFILE1=$(echo $CURFILE | cut -c 4-)**
```

**Code part before**

```
cp -a $AUTOFILE $AUTOFILE.old > $AUTOFILE.new
for file in /../pictures/*; do
    CURFILE="$(basename "$file")"
    cat <<EOF >> $AUTOFILE.new
file "$CURFILE" {
```

**Code part after changes**

```
cp -a $AUTOFILE $AUTOFILE.old > $AUTOFILE.new
for file in /../pictures/*; do
    CURFILE="$(basename "$file")"
    CURFILE1=$(echo $CURFILE | cut -c 4-)**
    cat <<EOF >> $AUTOFILE.new
file "$CURFILE1" {
```

Hello, can someone help me with bash script?
I am working to create auto fill file with information about existing files in directory with some params and more code on it...

Problem is that all files are using prefix ex.: **f1.file**, so I need to remove **f1.** and leave only **file**. Information about found files is stored as information "Text" in one single file.

I need to use some function in bash when files are generating and auto remove prefix in this line **`file "$CURFILE" {`**. CURFILE is the name as example: f1.file and I need to remove that **f1.**

**Just to be more concrete:**

1. Bash generates text file from all files in directory with custom parameters from code.
2. Problem is that text is generated with prefix f1,f2,f3.... because file names is f1.picture f2.test etc..
3. I need to show in data file only string without f1,f2,f3... etc..
4. Can someone help me to modify this line with some function? (Seed etc I know there is, but I don't know how to addapt it to existing line. Thank you!

Comment: [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please don't post fragments of code.

See [How to create a Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Let me rephrase your question in the way we use to do it at SO:

You have a variable `CURFILE` containing the string `f1.file` and you want it to contain `file` instead. Just do:

```
CURFILE=${CURFILE#*.}
```

Assuming the prefix you have to remove is delimited by a `.`, `${CURFILE#*.}` will remove any string followed by a dot from the front of your string.

Comment: Hello @Pierre, thanks for help, but strange thing is that it doesn't delete needed part, also I found many files that has this full name: f1.pic.s3 so I need only to delete f1. part, but first time doing something with bash, so every help from anyone is appreciated. :(

Comment: @zte813 Why did you accept the answer as correct if it did not solve your problem? Instead edit your question and clarify.

Comment: If the string in `CURFILE` contains `f1.pic.s3`, `${CURFILE#*.}` will contain `pic.s3`, but `${CURFILE##*.}` will contain `s3`. The operator `#` deletes the shortest matching string `*.`, `##` matches the longest one.

Comment: @Gerhard both solutions can work and is working, but used more simple option with cut.

Answer (score 1):

According your code, you always want to create a new variable `CURFILE1`, which is identical to `CURFILE`, but without the first 3 characters. It is unneccessary to use command substitution with child processes for this. Just do a

```
CURFILE1=${CURFILE#???}
```

If you want to ensure that only a `f1.` is removed, and not, say, an initial `f2.`, to instead a

```
CURFILE1=${CURFILE#f1.}
```