# sed to strip multi-part file extension from file pathname

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to compose a sed command to remove all trailing extensions from file names that have more than one in sequence separated by '.' eg:

```
/a/b/c.gz -> /a/b/c
/a/b/c.tar.gz -> /a/b/c rather than /a/b/c.tar
```

Notice that only the filename should be truncated; dots on parent directories are to be preserved.

```
/a/b.c/d.tar.gz -> /a/b.c/d
```

never

```
/a/b.c/d.tar, /a/b or /a/b/d
```

Therefore simply remove everything after the first '.' is not a solution.

I have a command that works OK as long as there is at least one '/' in the file name (or path rather). I'm not sure how to enhance in order to also cover single element (only filename) cases:

```
sed 's/^\(.*\/[^.\/]*\)[^\/]*$/\1/' list_of_filepaths.txt \
   > output_filepaths_wo_extensions.txt
```

So, the command above does the right thing with:

```
./abc.tar.gz, parent/.../abc.tar.gz, /abc.tar.gz
```

It does not work for single element (only filename) cases:

```
abc.tar.gz
```

Of course, this is not surprising since it isn't matching the slash '/' anywhere.

Although adding a second sed command to deal with the '/' free case is trivial, I would like to cover all cases with a single command as it seems to me that it should be possible.

For example, I was hopping that this one would work, but it does not work for either:

```
sed 's/^\(.*?\/\)?\([^.\/]*\)[^\/]*$/\1\2/'
```

So, in this attempt of mine, the first (additional) group would capture the optional '/' containing prefix preceding the last '/'. In case of a slash free file-path that group would simply be empty.

Comment: With your shown samples. How about using like `sed 's/\..*//' Input_file`?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 good try.... I guess I didn't add enough examples. that would not work with ```/a/b.c/d.e.g``` you would get ```/a/b``` instead of ```/a/b.c/d```. Will add the example.

Comment: `.*?` is not supported in `sed`; you want `[^/]*` (and probably switch to a different delimiter so you don't have to backslash-escape all the literal slashes). A more efficient (but more verbose) solution would be to use the shell's built-in [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) facilities.

Comment: @tripleee sounds promising, could you promote your comment to a fully fledged answer?

Comment: I added a second duplicate which covers this ground.

Comment: @tripleee not sure that is the same situation, there are similarities  but is not quite the same. Notice that the part that is engulfing the '/' coming from the left must be  actually greedy (to preserve all parent dirs) and not un-greedy as in the example.... otherwise if you se how that other question is giving a straight (trivial) answer to this one could you please post a full working sed command? .

Comment: `dir=${file%/*}; file=${file##*/}; file=$dir/${file%%.*}`

Comment: @tripleee is there a single sed command solution as per the question or must one delegate on bash (or perl)

Comment: You have it wrong, you are already running the shell and you don't want to delegate to `sed`.

Comment: @tripleee perhaps is just me but I like single liners that don't rely on stuffing several commands on a line separated with ';'. In my case I'm going to get a few thousand of these file names coming as the output of another command; Pipe them into a sed (with a single command if possible) rather than loading them into environment variables within a bash file reading loop or xargs and calling into another 3 liner bash script ... is more elegant/less cumbersome.

Comment: If your `sed` supports `-E` or `-r`, try `sed -E 's%(.*/)?([^/.]*)\..*%\1\2%'`. If not, maybe try `\?`but e.g. Mac `sed` does not support that at all; you can fake it with `sed 's%\(.*/\)*\([^./]*\)\..*%\1\2%'`

Comment: Your question exhibits a simple `echo` but for filtering a pipe, `sed` is definitely preferred.

Comment: @tripleee yes, the echo is just a convenient way to test if it works, and to show the problem in the simplest terms.

Comment: I guess I can change the question to show would a sed command would we preferable.

Comment: @tripleee fyi your bash solution above result in some edge case funky behavior. A simple filename without extension nor parent dirs result in duplicating the name with a '/' in between. Eg. 'hello' -> 'hello/hello'

Comment: @tripleee however the sed for mac solution is working, thanks very much.

Comment: a bash solution, using parameter expansion, is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/965069/724039

Comment: @Luuk that does not work with the case ```/a/b.c/d.e.f``` as we want ```/a/b.c/d``` but what I would get is ```/a/b```; dots in parent directories should be unchanged.